# Angular momentum commutator in QFT/the roles of coordinates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, angular-momentum, commutator, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

this is my first question on this site, so please correct me if I break any convention.
It arose as part of homework, but I suppose that there is some deeper irritation behind it.

We are supposed to verify that the relativistic angular-momentum operator (in any quantum field theory) satisfies the desired commutation relations. We found in class the conserved currents

$$M^{\mu\nu\tau}=x^\nu T^{\mu\tau}-x^\tau T^{\mu\nu}$$

and the corresponding charges

$$\mathcal{J}^{\nu\tau}=\int d^3 x M^{0\nu\tau}.$$

We are to show that these satisfy the known commutation relations for the Lorentz group generators

$$[\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu},\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}]=i(\eta^{\nu\rho}\mathcal{J}^{\mu\sigma}-\eta^{\mu\rho}\mathcal{J}^{\nu\sigma}-\eta^{\nu\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\mu\rho}+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\nu\rho}).$$

In the lecture we have proven that the commutator with the conserved charge generates the symmetry. Applied to the case here I would conclude that

$$[T^{0\mu}(x),\phi(x')]=-i\delta(x-x')\partial_\alpha \phi(x)\eta^{\alpha\mu}$$

for any quantum field $\phi$ (since the infinitesimal change upon spacetime translation, which is the symmetry corresponding to the energy-momentum tensor, is given by the derivative). Furthermore, an analogous formula should hold for any operator that is constructed out of field operators, so also for $T^{\mu\nu}$ itself. (This follows, I think, more or less from Weinberg, *The Quantum Theory of Fields*, vol. 1, e.g. eq. (7.3.52). However I am not sure about his notation.)

Now if I want to compute the commutator, I get

$$[\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu},\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}]=\int d^3 x d^3 x' [x^\mu T^{0\nu}(x),{x'}^\rho T^{0\sigma}(x')]-[x^\nu T^{0\mu}(x),{x'}^\sigma T^{0\rho}(x')]-[x^\mu T^{0\nu}(x),{x'}^\sigma T^{0\rho}(x')]+[x^\nu T^{0\mu}(x),{x'}^\sigma T^{0\rho}(x')].$$

My problem is what to do with the $x$ and $x'$. If I regard them as part of the quantum field, I would get more terms from the product rule. However I thought that they were in the case here simple scalars, since after all, I am integrating over them. Surely multiplication with the scalar $x$ (resp. $x'$) cannot affect the quantum mechanical commutator? Furthermore, if I look in Weinberg's book at the unnamed equation before eq. (7.4.19), it seems to me like indeed one does not differentiate explicitly occurring coordinates.

Thus, continuing with the assumption that I can pull out the coordinates of the commutator, I get, applying first the $\delta$-distribution and then integrating by parts,
$$[\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu},\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}]=\int d^3 x d^3 x' x^\mu {x'}^\rho(-i\delta(x-x')\partial_\alpha T^{0\sigma}(x))\eta^{\alpha\nu}-x^\nu {x'}^\sigma(-i\delta(x-x')\partial_\alpha T^{0\sigma}(x))\eta^{\alpha\mu}-x^\mu {x'}^\sigma(-i\delta(x-x')\partial_\alpha T^{0\rho})\eta^{\alpha\nu}+x^\nu {x'}^\sigma(-i\delta(x-x')\partial_\alpha T^{0\rho})\eta^{\alpha\mu}=$$
$$=\int d^3 x i(\partial_\alpha x^\mu)x^\rho T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\alpha\nu}+i(\partial_\alpha x^\rho)x^\mu T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\alpha\nu}-i(\partial_\alpha x^\nu)x^\rho T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\alpha\mu}-i(\partial_\alpha x^\rho)x^\nu T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\alpha\mu}-i(\partial_\alpha x^\mu)x^\sigma T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\alpha\nu}-i(\partial_\alpha x^\sigma)x^\mu T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\alpha\nu}+i(\partial_\alpha x^\nu)x^\sigma T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\alpha\mu}+i(\partial_\alpha x^\sigma)x^\nu T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\alpha\mu}=$$
$$=\int d^3 x ix^\mu T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\rho\nu}-ix^\nu T^{0\sigma}(x)\eta^{\rho\mu}-ix^\mu T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\sigma\nu}+ix^\nu T^{0\rho}(x)\eta^{\sigma\mu}.$$
(due to $\partial_\mu x^\nu=\delta_\mu^\nu$ and some cancelling of terms).

Going back to the definition of the commutator, I recognize that this is the negative of the same term with $\mu\leftrightarrow\rho$, $\nu\leftrightarrow\sigma$. Therefore I can anti-symmetrize this expression over these indices. Comparing with the definition of $\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu}$ again, I obtain
$$[\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu},\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}]=\frac{1}{2}i(\eta^{\nu\rho}\mathcal{J}^{\mu\sigma}-\eta^{\mu\rho}\mathcal{J}^{\nu\sigma}-\eta^{\nu\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\mu\rho}+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\nu\rho}).$$

I would be totally happy if there were not the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ due to the anti-symmetrization. I have been unable to spot the error, and although it might be a very trivial one, I have become quite confused what I are to differentiate here and what not.

My tutor told me that "we are computing in position basis, and here $T^{0\mu}$ is just given by $\partial^\mu$". Then I would get instead different terms, but I am not very convinced.

So could maybe someone clear up my confusion and explain what actually is an operator here and what not? Thank you in advance.